# direction rtl not working in wkhtml to pdf

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf in asp.net c# application.I have following table.when i generate this table to wkhtltopdf then dir="rtl" not working.My code is following

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul class="rtl">
                <li> شسشيبسيسيب لبي يبليس ل يبل سي ليل س يبل سي يبسل سي يبسل سي لش
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css">
    .rtl {
        direction: rtl; 
        text-align: right;
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override; 
    }
</style>
```

How can i give direction in rtl

Answer (score 1):

That should work.

But you can also try using the `dir` attribute on an element:

```
    <td>
        <ul dir="rtl">
            <li> شسشيبسيسيب لبي يبليس ل يبل سي ليل س يبل سي يبسل سي يبسل سي لش
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
```

Both your original and the `dir` tag appear to work. Here's a Plunkr to try - you can comment/uncomment each block and both seem to behave the same with the list displaying the list icon to the right with text flowing left.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RCQQPozhnBLQ0XkfFRYX?p=preview

Here's a related blog post I wrote the other day that has more detail on the `dir` tag and managing RTL in ASP.NET and Angular.

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/May/23/Right-To-Left-RTL-Text-Display-in-Angular-and-ASPNET

Comment: thanks, `dir="rtl"` worked, css attribute did not